# Call a number programatically when app is in background

Tags: android

How can we perform a call to any number when application is in the background using volume key (number set by own self-using application)?

When I press up the volume key 3 times, I want the app to call my Dad's number even if the app is in background.

Comment: So what you tried so far, don't expect here to write the whole program for you.

Comment: Check the answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Update your question title "Call a number programmatically when app is in background"

Comment: Kindly, post some code that you tried, please dont expect people to work for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Using following code you can achieve it -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Also, don't forget to add the permission for the same in Manifest file -

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And lastly you need to check for the volume up button event to trigger the call -

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
    down = false;
  } else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
    up = false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Based on the condition you can achieve the same. Thanks :)

Comment: If the OP uses the exact same code then this will produce `java.lang.NullPointerException`, and as a result, the app will get crashed

Comment: Call phone is runtime permission isnt? Also background stuff are more restricted in Nougat and above versions

Comment: @Talha Exactly that's why I mentioned let me know for further concerns. Thanks for the valuable input tho.

Comment: @MubashirOpi what's the target version of your application? and kindly share your code for the background process so I can help.

Comment: @DudeCoder Cuz you aren't answering the question and rather helping others you are just creating a mess. If you have a better solution post it here and help him.